# Is there a more efficient way of nesting three for loops?

Tags: r

I have been struggling for a while in converting the code below to use the *apply family of functions, so am now asking the StackOverflow community for a little help. Some background, this is part of a method I am developing to analyze propensity score methods for three groups. As such, I am starting with three matrices representing the distances (difference in propensity scores) between each pair of groups. That is, matrix d1 is A x B, d2 is B x C, and d3 is C x A. What I need to do is find triplets that minimize the overall distance as well as be less than some caliper. I've simplified the example as best as I could to run while getting at what I am trying to.

Couple of notes:

- The distance less than the caliper check (`row1 <- row1[row1 < caliper]`) could be done at the end if I were to simply create a data.frame (or matrix) of all possible combinations. However, even with the small number of groups I set here would result in 3,000 rows!
- I order the vectors before moving onto the next step. Again, if I were to have a matrix of all possible combinations this could be eliminated. In my current version I have another line that will only look at the n smallest elements in order to reduce the execution time.
- This example has pretty small groups. I am working on a dataset where the groups have between 5,000 and 8,000 subjects each.

Thanks in advance for any help. I am working on a paper for this and would be happy to give a acknowledgements. Also, I plan on attending the useR! conference in Spain and will buy a beer for whomever helps :-)

```
groups <- c('Control','Treat1','Treat2')
group.sizes <- c(15, 10, 20)
set.seed(2112)

d1 <- matrix(abs(rnorm(group.sizes[1] * group.sizes[2], mean=0, sd=1)), 
             nrow=group.sizes[1], ncol=group.sizes[2],
             dimnames=list(1:group.sizes[1], 
                          (group.sizes[1]+1):(group.sizes[1] + group.sizes[2])) )
d2 <- matrix(abs(rnorm(group.sizes[2] * group.sizes[3], mean=0, sd=1)), 
             nrow=group.sizes[2], ncol=group.sizes[3],
             dimnames=list((group.sizes[1]+1):(group.sizes[1] + group.sizes[2]), 
                          (group.sizes[2] + group.sizes[1] + 1):(sum(group.sizes)) ) )
d3 <- matrix(abs(rnorm(group.sizes[3] * group.sizes[1], mean=0, sd=1)), 
             nrow=group.sizes[3], ncol=group.sizes[1],
             dimnames=list((group.sizes[2] + group.sizes[1] + 1):(sum(group.sizes)), 
                          1:group.sizes[1]) )

caliper <- 1
results <- data.frame(v1=character(), v2=character(), v3=character(),
                      d1=numeric(), d2=numeric(), d3=numeric())
for(i1 in dimnames(d1)[[1]]) {
    row1 <- d1[i1,]
    row1 <- row1[row1 < caliper]
    row1 <- row1[order(row1)]
    for(i2 in names(row1)) {
        row2 <- d2[i2,]
        row2 <- row2[row2 < caliper]
        row2 <- row2[order(row2)]
        for(i3 in names(row2)) {
            val <- d3[i3,i1]
            if(val < caliper) {
                results <- rbind(results, 
                        data.frame(v1=i1, v2=i2, v3=i3,
                                d1=row1[i2], d2=row2[i3], d3=val))
            }
        }
    }
}
head(results)
```

Comment: Buy a beer ? Is this not considered as a form of bribery on StackOverflow ? :)

Comment: Apparently the `df.sizes` vector is missing.

Comment: Sorry about that juba, fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to look at the code but I can't manage to understand what his goal is precisely. What do you mean exactly by "What I need to do is find triplets that minimize the overall distance" ? And what do your `results` data frame represent ?

Comment: Hi Juba. I am starting with 3 matrices that represent the distances (of propensity scores specifically) between each pair of groups, so the dimensions are AxB, BxC, CxA. What my for loop does is loop through each row in the first matrix, find small elements from group B. Those elements are then the rows in the second matrix. For those rows find small distances to C. For those elements I can finish the loop using the third matrix. The results data frame are candidate triplets (ie one from each group) where the total sum from the three matrices is minimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more work, I have figured out how to replace the three nested for loops with nested `lapply` function calls. To simplify testing the two approaches, I moved them to functions which are included below. This first chuck sets up the three matrices:

```
group.sizes <- c(15, 10, 20)
set.seed(2112)

d1 <- matrix(abs(rnorm(group.sizes[1] * group.sizes[2], mean=0, sd=1)), 
             nrow=group.sizes[1], ncol=group.sizes[2],
             dimnames=list(1:group.sizes[1], 
                          (group.sizes[1]+1):(group.sizes[1] + group.sizes[2])) )
d2 <- matrix(abs(rnorm(group.sizes[2] * group.sizes[3], mean=0, sd=1)), 
             nrow=group.sizes[2], ncol=group.sizes[3],
             dimnames=list((group.sizes[1]+1):(group.sizes[1] + group.sizes[2]), 
                          (group.sizes[2] + group.sizes[1] + 1):(sum(group.sizes)) ) )
d3 <- matrix(abs(rnorm(group.sizes[3] * group.sizes[1], mean=0, sd=1)), 
             nrow=group.sizes[3], ncol=group.sizes[1],
             dimnames=list((group.sizes[2] + group.sizes[1] + 1):(sum(group.sizes)), 
                          1:group.sizes[1]) )
```

**Now the results with times**

```
> system.time(results.forloops <- forloops(d1, d2, d3))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.129   0.370   2.530 
> system.time(results.apply <- nestedapply(d1, d2, d3))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.019   0.000   0.019
```

Without much surprise, the `lapply` method is substantially faster, even with this small example. Warning, you can try this with larger matrices by changing the `group.sizes` factor above but the nested loops take a very long time to complete when making even small jumps in sizes.

**Here are the functions:**

```
forloops <- function(d1, d2, d3, caliper=1) {
    results <- data.frame(v1=character(), v2=character(), v3=character(),
                          d1=numeric(), d2=numeric(), d3=numeric())
    for(i1 in dimnames(d1)[[1]]) {
        row1 <- d1[i1,]
        row1 <- row1[row1 < caliper]
        #row1 <- row1[order(row1)]
        for(i2 in names(row1)) {
            row2 <- d2[i2,]
            row2 <- row2[row2 < caliper]
            #row2 <- row2[order(row2)]
            for(i3 in names(row2)) {
                val <- d3[i3,i1]
                if(val < caliper) {
                    results <- rbind(results, 
                                     data.frame(v1=i1, v2=i2, v3=i3,
                                               d1=row1[i2], d2=row2[i3], d3=val))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    results$total <- results$d1 + results$d2 + results$d3
    results <- results[order(results$total),]
    results <- results[!duplicated(results[,c('v1','v2')]), ]
    invisible(results)
}

nestedapply <- function(d1, d2, d3, caliper=1) {

    d1[d1 > caliper] <- NA
    d2[d2 > caliper] <- NA
    d3[d3 > caliper] <- NA

    results <- lapply(dimnames(d1)[[1]], FUN=function(i1) {
        row1 <- d1[i1,]
        row1 <- row1[!is.na(row1)]
        lapply(names(row1), FUN=function(i2) {
            row2 <- d2[i2,]
            row2 <- row2[!is.na(row2)]
            lapply(names(row2), FUN=function(i3) {
                val <- d3[i3,i1]
                if(is.na(val)) {
                    return(c())
                } else {
                    c(i1, i2, i3, row1[i2], row2[i3], val)
                }
            })
        })
    })
    results <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(results), ncol=6, byrow=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    names(results) <- c('v1','v2','v3','d1','d2','d3')
    results$d1 <- as.numeric(results$d1)
    results$d2 <- as.numeric(results$d2)
    results$d3 <- as.numeric(results$d3)
    results$total <- results$d1 + results$d2 + results$d3
    invisible(results)
}
```